# Is this where my HVAC air filter goes?

Tags: hvac, air-filter

I moved into a home that was poorly taken care of by the homeowner before.  It dawned on me today that I've never replaced the HVAC filter (I guess I'm bad at taking care of the house too :) ) in the year that I've lived here.  The thought came up since I was wondering how dust accumulates so quickly in my house.  So I went to look for the filter at my air handler unit in the basement.  I couldn't find any obvious location that looked like it accepted an air filter except this hatch below the air handler unit:

[image: Hatch open]

The hatch, when closed, looks like this:

[image: ai]

I also tried taking off some of the panels on the air handler itself, but they're mainly full of the heat exchanger coils and other sundry items; I didn't see a filter.

However, there's nothing inside.  Did the previous owner just not put a filter in at all, or should I look elsewhere?  My return air registers are all the small rectangular kind, not the large squarish kind.

If it is where the filter goes, how would I go about figuring out the size of the filter?  Do I just measure the depth and the width of the opening?

Comment: If you have the manufacturer, model and serial number of that unit then the manufacturer may have the information and even the parts you need.

Comment: If you turn the fan on and open that duct, does the air blow down towards the ground or up towards the sky?